# Category and Subcategory

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

Пишу тесты для студентов у меня в json  есть категории и вопросы привязаны к номеру категории. Например есть категории Электроника Бытовая химия и Продукты как сделать что бы Электроника имела под категории Мобильные телефоны  и тд...  и что бы и эти подкатегории имели свои под ... категории?`

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_category": "1",
      "category_name": "Продукты"
    },`
 "items": [
    {
      "question_category": "2",
      "category_name": "Электроника"
    },`
}
```

и вопросы

```
  },
    {
      "question": "Хворому з ревматоїдним артритом тривалий час вводили гiдрокортизон. У нього з’явилися гiперглiкемiя, полiурiя, глюкозурiя, спрага. Цi ускладнення лiкування є наслiдком активацiї такого процесу: ",
      "answers": [
        " Глюконеогенез",
        " Глiкогенолiз",
        " Глiкогенез",
        " Глiколiз",
        " Лiполiз"
      ],
      "correct_answer":0,
      "question_category":"1"
    },
    {
      "question": "Для зняття марення i галюцинацiй у хворої на шизофренiю лiкар використав амiназин. Який механiзм антипсихотичної дiї препарату? ",
      "answers": [
        " Блокада адренергiчних i дофамiнергiчних процесiв в ЦНС",
        " Стимуляцiя адренергiчних i дофамiнергiчних процесiв в ЦНС",
        " Стимуляцiя холiнергiчних процесiв в ЦНС",
        " Блокада холiнергiчних процесiв в ЦНС",
        " Iнгiбування зворотнього нейронального захоплення МАО"
      ],
      "correct_answer":0,
      "question_category":"1"
    },
    {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, тут нет единого првального решения, но предложу такое:

**массив категорий теперь выглядит так**

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "question_category": "0",
      "category_name": "Продукты"
    },
    {
      "question_category": "1",
      "category_name": "Электроника",
      "items": [ //подкатегории категории
          {
              "question_category": "0",
              "category_name": "Мобильные телефоны"
              "items": [ ... ] // подкатегории тоже могут иметь 
          }
          // и так далее
      ]
    },
}
```

**и вопросы**

```
{
  "question": "Хворому з ревматоїдним артритом тривалий час вводили гiдрокортизон. У нього з’явилися гiперглiкемiя, полiурiя, глюкозурiя, спрага. Цi ускладнення лiкування є наслiдком активацiї такого процесу: ",
  "answers": [
    " Глюконеогенез",
    " Глiкогенолiз",
    " Глiкогенез",
    " Глiколiз",
    " Лiполiз"
  ],
  "correct_answer":0,
  "question_category":[1, 0] //это уже массив и он содержит путь к нужной категории. [1, 0] - Мобильные телефоны. [0] - Продукты
}
```

А как все это связать уже сам решай. Учти, что такая структура подразумевает хранение всех вопросов в одном файле. Если их будет много (вопросов), то сложно будет структурировать да и файл получится большим. И еще раз: вариантов решения - масса, буду раз, если дал хорошую подсказку)

Comment: Спасибо большое